# Shapiro-Wilk and Kolmogrov-Smirnoff contradict each other

Tags: spss

I am testing for normality. I have 5 subjects. I am looking to see the distribution for my baseline data. The normality score that I got for SW and KS contradict each other. SW said m data is normally distributed while KS says otherwise. How can this happen? What does it mean? And what should I do? Do I choose and pick either one?

Comment: Does'nt make much sense to test for normality based on 5 observations, no power. What is your real goal?

Comment: i just want to see the distribution of pre-test data for those 5 subjects. there are 4 tests involved and i am trying to look at them separately. i am very new to spss and i am running out of hand here. thanks for your response.

Comment: Please don't post two versions of essentially the same question; if there's some issue with the first one you post you edit it rather than posting again